# SQL Query GETGATE() and DATEPART Format

Tags: sql, sql-server

The individual who implemented a db, setup the date column format = 'MONTH, YEAR"

Example 'December, 2017'

In order to automate query, I need to pass date as a parameter to the where clause.

So, I started to work with the DATE function. Is there a way to convert DATEPART from integer to full month name?

```
 DECLARE @dtDate DATE
 DECLARE @dtMonth varchar(50)
 DECLARE @dtYear varchar(50)

 SET @dtDate = GETDATE();
 SET @dtMonth = convert(varchar, DATEPART(mm, @dtDate))
 SET @dtYear = convert(varchar, DATEPART(yyyy, @dtDate))
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. SET @dtMonth = DATENAME(MONTH, @dtDate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `datename`

```
declare @dtDate datetime = '2017-01-01'
declare @dtMonth nvarchar(10)
SET @dtMonth = datename(month, @dtDate)
print @dtMonth

Output:January
```